# Getting MQ error log after deploying Windows services

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services, ibm-mq

I have a windows service which is calling internally WCF service which is connecting to Webshphere MQ.

I have two threads in my code ,one for sending messages to the queue and other one for receiving messages from queue.

The problem is whenever I am installing  the windows service a MQ log (AMQ3780.0.FDC) in which I am not writing is getting created and keep on increasing. I am not sure what is causing the issue,If I debug the code using Test Classes I am able to send the messages and receive the messages.

Please help me to understand this issue.

Regards,
Ishan Trikha

Comment: What is the probeid and callstack + comments of the fdc?

Comment: Probe Id:- DN729001 and contents of the file says some connection error.When I am trying to comment my second thread (receiver) then log doen't get generated.

Comment: An FDC is indications the underlying code has an issue which needs investigation, and could definitely account for problems. Its difficult to work with limited info - Can you paste in the comment1 field (or ideally as much of the top box and first section [not the trace history] of the fdc, editing out anything private). There are known causes, eg http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC90233 , but without more info its hard to guess. 

What version + fixpack are you running (client and server)?

Comment: MQM Function Stack
ManagedNmqiMQ.MQCONNX(String,MQConnectOptions,Phconn,out int,out int)
ManagedNmqiMQ.DoConn(String,MQConnectOptions,out MQHCONN,out MQLONG,out MQLONG)
MQFAP.MakeConnection(String,MQConnectOptions,out MQLONG,out MQLONG,out MQHCONN)
MQFAPConnection.InitialFlows(MQConnectOptions,Boolean,ref int,ref int)
MQFAPConnection.SendConnAuth(MQConnectOptions,out MQLONG,out MQLONG)
MQTSH.Initialize(MQLONG,MQBYTE,MQBYTE,MQUSHORT)
xcsFFST..Version I am using is 7.0.

Comment: What's interesting was I install the same service on my local pointing to MQ in development server and know MQ log is not getting increased(generated itself)not sure what is happening and code is working as required.

Comment: So the stack and probe you have are a direct match for IC90233 (in fact, the same stack was flagged by the person who reported that apar). You are on 7.0.1.9/7.0.1.10 to see this so upgrade the client to 7.0.1.11...   Note your comment on not seeing it on your box may just mean you are at different maintenance levels for the client than the machine you are seeing the issues on. A problem was found, and checks added in the server code, plus diagnostic FDC in the client code to highlight if another scenario for the same problem was found... you trigger that which is the APAR mentioned.

Comment: I am using amqmdnet.dll for connecting to MQ I don't think ..MQ version on my local and the one dev will be a problem. Found one link https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014932066 but even it's not working for me.the exception in this link look similar to what I am getting but still no luck,

Comment: I think I found the problem,as I mentioned there were two threads one for sending messages and other for receiving messages from queue.The receiver thread continuously pooling around the queue and everytime it creates a new connection to the queuemanager so I added one condition if(this.queuemanager==null) this.queuemanager=getmqconnection() otherwise there is no need for making connection and somehow it worked.

Comment: So the FDC is being generated when an connection is being attempted. Doing less of them will obviously stop the file from continually growing - are you seeing one being created at all? Depending on th level of the server you talk to, its possible the FDC is purely informational, but you shouldnt be creating them on a regular basis even if its a one off. You havent answered my question about versions, but if you are in the range I am talking about then upgrading is the way to solve this 'properly'.

Comment: The version I am using is 7.0,the .FDC file is getting generated but not keep on increase and the size too is in KB's.I think you are right for solving this problem permanently we need to install upgraded version.Thanks Jason for you help and prompt responses.Will keep posting in this thread if i found something new.